# How to install grub to a CD-RW?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, bios

My very old server only has BIOS, no UEFI, and the boot order routine aborts booting when it encounters a drive larger than 2TB. The boot order is: CDs, HDDs, USBs, network. I cannot change the boot order because I don't know the BIOS password.

How can I install grub to a CD-R or CD-RW?

All of my HDD bays are taken by 4TB drives and I'm not changing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You will need a package named `grub-pc-bin` and another one named `xorriso`.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-pc-bin xorriso
```

2. 

```
mkdir ~/cdrom
mkdir ~/cdrom/boot
mkdir ~/cdrom/boot/grub
```

3. 

```
nano ~/cdrom/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

4. Here's an example of a `grub.cfg` file that boots the first hard disk:

```
set timeout=10
set default=0

menuentry "Boot from Hard Drive" {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    chainloader +1
}
```

5. You will need to use `grub-mkrescue` to create an ISO file that can be burned to a CD.

```
grub-mkrescue -o bootable.iso ~/cdrom
```

6. You can use a tool like `Brasero` or `k3b` to burn the ISO file to a CD. If you prefer to use the command line, you can use `cdrecord` (you might need to install it first with `sudo apt-get install cdrecord`):

```
sudo cdrecord -v speed=4 bootable.iso
```

7. Boot from CD.